# How can I get portions of a big response from an API using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, asynchronous, lazy-loading

I have a big API request that is giving me around 1000 results. As this request is too big, I need to split in several portions of response, so this is faster. I would like to query the 1000 results, but streaming the data as is coming with client-side

In the API request you are not allowed to put any parameter, so you retrieve the whole amount of posts. The response is a JSON mostly the same as Wordpress (but it is not Wordpress)

I have tried the same request from 10 to 10 results, but I have to do several queries to achieve the expected behaviour.

What I would like to get is from a request from 1000 results.

```
    fetch(api)
    .then((data) => ...)
    .then((data) => {
        //When loaded first 10 records show
        //When loaded next 10 records show
        ...
        // Until the 1000
    })
```

Is there any way that I could achieve that?

Comment: You need your server to support streaming data - the client can't force the server to split up the response

Comment: It is very important to know how you are acquiring your results. For instance, If you are using streaming, the data is coming simultaneously and you wont have to deal with this kind of problems.

where does your data coming from?

Comment: Hi @Simonare This is from the client-side and it is coming from an API, so the data is in another server. The example would be, I have a blog with 1000 posts in Wordpress, but I have a page done with HTML, CSS, JS and I need to retrieve those posts streaming the data.

Comment: Hi @MatthewHerbst so probably the best deal is doing several queries to retrieve that data, isn't it?

Comment: @RandyRandalf if the server supports that, then yes, that's certainly the simplest way to go

Comment: @RandyRandalf because the answer depends very much on what type of pagination the Wordpress API supports and not just how JS works, I've added the Wordpress tag and edited your title so you get more helpful responses.

Comment: I am wiling to bet that there is no issue with the call to get 1000 items. I am betting the issue is with writing out 1000 items at once. Unless that backend call is taking a long time, probably is just a clientside issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I have done is retrieved with many queries different pages, being the datatable updated gradually with new records from the new query

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways a backend can implement streaming/pagination, and the JS answer depends on which way the backend you're querying supports.

- Pagination via request parameters
- HTTP range requests (how online movies are streamed with seeking allowed)
- Websocket streaming (how web games work where players get real-time updates)

Because you mentioned you're querying Wordpress in your comment, I'll give an example for Wordpress here, but other APIs may have different ways of handling streaming/pagination.

The WordPress API supports pagination, as outlined here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

What you'll need to do is specifically request a page with an offset to get that portion of the results, like so:

```
 /wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&offset=1000
```

This will get the list of posts after post #1000, where each page has 100 results.

For other APIs you'll need to give more details for us to determine how to stream results.

Comment: Here the problem is you have to request every time you want a new page. What I would like to have is just a request, /wp/v2/posts and streaming the data that is coming (The API is not Wordpress, it was just an example)

Comment: You have to specifically specify what the API is, as the answer depends entirely on how the backend provides the data.  There is no generic JS solution to stream data from an endpoint that doesn't support streaming.  If you can give details about the backend you're using then we can provide examples of how to set it up to push results to a frontend in realtime.

Comment: I have edited the question so it is better clarified. The data is in a JSON response, the request doesn't allow any parameter to partition

Comment: Right, but we need to know what the API is to know whether it supports streaming, this cannot be solved with just JS, we need to know how the backend works.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to know how you are acquiring your results. For instance, If you are using streaming, the data is coming simultaneously and you wont have to deal with this kind of problems.

You can check the links below for back-end data streaming.

- [Socket.io](https://socket.io/)
- [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/)

> The WebSocket protocol enables interaction between a web client (such as a browser) and a web server with lower overheads, facilitating real-time data transfer from and to the server

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)